# Getting highest value based on a keyword

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I've a poorly structured SQLite database. Structure looks like this:

`ID      |      USERID     |       KEY       |     VALUE`

The key column contains the name of a bit of data for a user, that means I have multiple rows with the same USERID. What I want to do is filter it so I get the following output:

Go through the entire database and search for the highest value that matches a certain key. For instance:

```
ID     |      USERID     |       KEY         |     VALUE
1      |      banana     |       abc12       |     3
2      |      apple      |       def34       |     4
3      |     pineapple   |       abc12       |     5
```

I only want to run the check if the word in the KEY column (e.g. `abc12`) is found. So if `abc12` is the value of the column key it should check if it's value is higher then the last highest value. In the end, after running my query I should get the following result:

ID: 3 (since the value is 5, and it is the highest one out of `abc12` keyword).

I'm looking forward for your ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit: whoa jk for some reason I thought you wanted the second highest value.

You can just use

`SELECT ID 
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE KEY = [VALUE]
ORDER BY VALUE DESC
LIMIT 1`

(old answer)

Something like 

`SELECT VALUE 
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE KEY LIKE "%:value:%` (I'm assuming LIKE because you said it just wants contains, not a exact match)
ORDER BY VALUE DESC
LIMIT 1, 1 
`

`LIMIT 1,1` will select the second highest row (first row, offset 1). Not sure how this fails if there is only 1 row that matches.

Comment: I want it to match a certain key, ugh.

Comment: Oh my mistake, then use `=`.